# How to sort on an append in JS

Tags: javascript

First of all I'm very new to JS and still learning.
I'm trying to add a sort to the .append($address) whereby it sorts it by the numbers at the start of each address.

Would someone be able to guide me please.

```
function list_addresses(addresses) {

$('.postcode-found .addresses .select').html('');
$('.postcode-found .addresses .package-type').removeClass('active');

for (var x=0;x<addresses.length;x++) {
    var $address = $('<button/>',{
        type:'button',
        class:'btn-address',
        'data-address':addresses[x].address,
        'data-id':addresses[x].id,
        'data-available':addresses[x].available,
        'data-build_type':addresses[x].build_type,
        'data-activation_period':addresses[x].activation_period
    }).text( addresses[x].address.replace(/, ,/g, ', ') );
    $('.postcode-found .addresses .select').append($address);
}
}
```

Edit -
I have tried the following and also other examples to sort the array.

```
for (var x=0;x<addresses.length;x++) {
    addresses.sort();
```

Comment: Please put your own attempt at solving this into the question, ideally as [mre] (use the `<>` button)

Comment: Do you mean that you're adding an element to a list and wanting to re-sort the list afterward?  What have you tried and where are you stuck?  You might consider keeping an in-memory array of the data, sorting that, and re-rendering the UI based on that data.

Comment: I've added my latest attempt to the question. Sorry about that.

Comment: Basically addresses brings back a list of addresses, I want to sort that list by numerical order. At the moment the output has 15 Road Name,3 Road Name,83Road Name,40 Road Name etc.

Comment: `addresses.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a.address) - parseInt(b.address))`

Comment: Thank you Chris, it works a charm. And I'm now running through the following to learn some more. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: One last question if i may. Chris's suggestion works great, but when I have an address with no number it somehow get's inserted into the sorted numbers. Is there a way to list and sort numerical first followed by house names for example.